# SLF4J-Logback print root cause message

Tags: java, exception, logging, logback, slf4j

I am using SLF4J with Logback to log error messages. One of the observations was that some of the root cause requires `toString()` instead of `getMessage()`. For example, if an exception is wrapped under another, SLF4J prints 'null' of the root cause instead of the exception message which is indirectly referenced in `toString()`. Java util library logs fine. However, I have to use the SLF4J-Logback. Is there any way that overrides the default behaviour of SLF4J and logback.

```
class TestException extends Exception
        {
            private String exceptionCode;
            private String exceptionMessage;

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "TestException [exceptionCode=" + exceptionCode + ", exceptionMessage=" + exceptionMessage + "]";
            }
        }

        try
        {
            TestException testException = new TestException();
            testException.exceptionCode = "Test exception code";
            testException.exceptionMessage = "Test exception message";
            throw new IOException("Io message", testException);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error message ", e);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "Error message", e);
        }
```

Output presents itself with:

```
// SLF4J logging
java.io.IOException: Io message
    at test.Test.testMethod(Test.java:224)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:119)
Caused by: test.Test$1TestException: null
    at test.Test.testMethod(Test.java:221)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Nov 17, 2016 11:52:04 AM test.Test testMethod

// Java Util logging
SEVERE: Error message
java.io.IOException: Io message
    at test.Test.testMethod(Test.java:224)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:119)
Caused by: TestException [exceptionCode=Test exception code, exceptionMessage=Test exception message]
    at test.Test.testMethod(Test.java:221)
    ... 1 more
```